# Problem with Formidable Error : Request aborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I have an application with Node.js, Express.js , MongoDB and Javascript for front-end. I want to create file upload to add image . I use formidable and use AWS like cloud platform to save images too.

The problem is :
In my application , I have a form for add information about a car , for example: mark, model, year, location ,price, Choose image button and Submit button. When I fill the fields with data and choose image , then click on Submit button, in the console it write this:

```
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:122:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:598:9)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:589:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:381:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:666:12)
```

I put part of app.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const socketIO = require('socket.io')

// init app
const app = express();

// setup body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// configuration for autthentication
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// load helpers
const {requireLogin, ensureGuest} = require('./helpers/authHelper');
const {upload} = require('./helpers/aws');

// load passports
require('./passport/local');
require('./passport/facebook.js');

// receive image
app.post('/uploadImage',requireLogin,upload.any(),(req,res)=>{
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.on('file',(field,file)=>{
        console.log(file);
    });
    form.on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
    form.on('end',()=>{
        console.log('Image received successfully.');
    });
    form.parse(req);
});
```

Here is where I add "upload" in aws.js :

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multers3 = require('multer-s3');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId:keys.AWSAccessID,
    secretAccessKey: keys.AWSSecretKey,
    region: 'eu-north-1'
});

const s3 = new aws.S3({});

const upload = multer({
    storage: multers3({
        s3:s3,
        bucket: 'car-rental-application',
        ac1:'public-read',
        metadata:(req,file,cb)=>{
            cb(null,{fieldName:file.fieldname});
        }, 
        key: (req,file,cb)=>{
            cb(null,file.originalname);
        },
        rename: (fieldName,fileName) =>{
            return fileName.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        }
    })
});
exports.upload = upload;
```

And here is html form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">
            <form action="/listCar2" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="carID" value="{{car._id}}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pricePerHour">Price per hour</label>
                <input type="number" name="pricePerHour" id="pricePerhour" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pricePerWeek">Price per week</label>
                <input type="number" name="pricePerWeek" id="pricePerWeek" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="location">Location</label>
                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form-control" placeholder="street, city, state and zipcode " required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info upload-btn" type="button">Choose image</button>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="upload-input" style="display: none;" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">List a car</button>
            </div>
            </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    // fetch location using javascript
function initMap(){
    var location = document.getElementById('location');
    var Autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(location);
}

// jquery code starts here
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.upload-btn').on('click',function(){
        $('#upload-input').click();
    });
    $('#upload-input').on('change', function(){
        var uploadInput = $('#upload-input');
        if(uploadInput.val() != ''){
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', uploadInput[0].files[0]);
            
            // make ajax request to send image to database
            $.ajax({
                url: '/uploadImage',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function() {
                    uploadInput.val('');
                }
            })
         }
    })
})

</script>
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZa44WBMahTn9Zf2z9x6fKiZTMQQh3vbw&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

How can I fix this problem?